# Передать данные из компонента в сервис. Angular 2

Tags: angular

Каким передать данные из компонента в сервис?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примером взаимодействия между сервисом и компонентом:

**Сервис:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    myMethod$: Observable<any>;
    private myMethodSubject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {
        this.myMethod$ = this.myMethodSubject.asObservable();
    }

    myMethod(data) {
        console.log(data); // У нас есть данные! Давайте вернем их, чтобы подписчики могли его использовать!
        // тут мы можем делать что-нибудь с данными
        this.myMethodSubject.next(data);
    }
}
```

**Компонент1 (отправитель):**

```
export class SomeComponent {
    public data: Array<any> = MyData;

    public constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.myMethod(this.data);
    }
}
```

**Компонент2 (получатель):**

```
export class SomeComponent2 {
    public data: Array<any> = MyData;

    public constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.myMethod$.subscribe((data) => {
                this.data = data; // И тут тоже мы можем пользоваться нашими данными!
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Объяснение:**

`My Service` управляет `data`. Вы можете по-прежнему работать `data`, если хотите, но лучше оставить это для `Component2`.
В основном `MyService` получает`data` из `Component1` и отправляет его тому, кто подписался на метод`myMethod ()`.

`Component1` отправляет`data` в `MyService`, и это все, что он делает.
`Component2` подписывается на`myMethod ()`, поэтому каждый раз, когда`myMethod ()`вызывается,`Component2` будет слушать и получать все, что возвращает `myMethod ()`.

Ответ взят и переведен из вопроса [Angular 2 send data from component to service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066905/angular-2-send-data-from-component-to-service/44067238#44067238)